# How do I measure the performance of the blocks inside the function in iOS Unit Testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

Function type to be tested:

```
[self someFunctionOnSuccess:^{

    //Test this block with a test case and check its performance

} onFailure:^{

    //Test this block with a test case and check its performance

}];
```

There are different test cases that I could write for passing and failing the function.

My Question is:
How to measure the performace of these closures or blocks after they have completed the execution. For a simple method I could straight away use:

```
- (void)testPerformance {

    [self measureBlock:^{
         //Test the performance of this function.
        [self simpleFunction];

     }];

}
```